# Differential equation involving relative risk function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finance

A utility function $U$ whose corresponding relative risk aversion function is a linear, increasing function satisfies the differential equation

$-x\frac{U''(x)}{U'(x)}=ax+b$

for some constants $a>o$ and $b\in \mathbf{R}$

Show that

$U(x)=c \int _0 ^x t^{-b}e^{-at} dt$, where $c>0$ is an arbitrary constant.

---

I massaged the equation so it becomes friendly.

$-x \frac{d^2U}{dx^2}=(ax+b)\frac{dU}{dx}$

Letting $\frac{dU}{dx}=v$

$ -x\frac{dv}{dx}=(ax+b)v$

Dividing by $(-x)$

$ \frac{dv}{dx}+axv=-\frac{b}{x}v$

$ \frac{dv}{dx}+\frac{b}{x}v=-axv$

I.F

$e^{\int \frac{b}{x}  dx}=x^b$

$\therefore vx^b=b\int x^ba dx$

$\therefore v= \frac{a}{b+1}x+Cx^{-b}$

$U=\int \frac{a}{b+1}x+Cx^{-b}$

But the answer is

$U(x)=c\int^x_0 t^{-b}e^{-at}dt$

I cannot understand where the $t$ comes to sit in the equation.

Comment: Up to "$x\frac{dv}{dx} + axv = -bv$" you are good. However, your choice of integrating factor is not appropriate. Indeed, you are supposed to take the exponential of the integral of whatever's in front of $v$, but only if the coefficient of $\frac{dv}{dx}$ is $1$. Furthermore, you still have a $v$ term left over on the RHS.

Comment: @JoeyZou, Is it good now. But I am still stuck.

Comment: It is better, but you still have $v$ left over on the RHS. You should move that over to the LHS before applying an integrating factor. Perhaps you should review why integrating factors work to see why this is important.

Comment: @JoeyZou, you were a great help to me. Thanks buddy. I could get it finally.

Answer (score 0):

$$-x \frac{d^2U}{dx^2}=(ax+b)\frac{dU}{dx}$$

Letting $\frac{dU}{dx}=v$

$$-x \frac{dv}{dx}=(ax+b)v$$

Rearranging

$$-\frac{x}{v} \frac{dv}{dx}=(ax+b)$$

$$ -\int\frac{1}{v} dv= \int (a+\frac{b}{x}) dx $$

$$ v=e^{-ax}x^b$$

By taking $t$ as a dummy variable.

$$U(x)= \int ^x_0(e^{-at}t^{-b}) dt$$

Comment: You are much closer now--there's still a few issues though. Note that integrating $-\frac{1}{v}\frac{dv}{dx}$ is not $-\int{(\ln v)dv}$: it *is* $-\ln v$...plus an arbitrary constant. This turns into the arbitrary constant required in the question, which is currently missing in your answer.

Comment: @JoeyZou, that was a typo error. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You are still missing the arbitrary constant. Take care of that, and you are done.